# Trying to understand async.forEach

Tags: node.js

I am currently trying to learn the async module for node.js. Below is an example demonstrating how to use async.forEach.

```
var async   = require('async'),
    request = require('request');

var results = {};

function done(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('done! results: %j', results);
}

var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function iterator(value, callback) {
  request.post({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
      body: JSON.stringify(value)
    },

    function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      results[value] = JSON.parse(body);
      callback();
    });
}

async.forEach(collection, iterator, done);
```

So async.forEach iterated through each element in the collection, and each element is then passed into "value" in the iterator function...but I don't really understand whats being passed into callback? (which is then executed at the end of iterator)

Comment: Consider using promises instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will receive an array of the results of the individual operations – whatever you pass to the callback.

Since you don't pass anything to the callback, it will receive an array of `undefined`.

Comment: so will callback() be executed if it is undefined?

Comment: @WerdnaKof: Huh? `callback()` will be executed whenever you call it.  Which callback are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So if the callback parameter in the iterator function is undefined, how can the callback() be executed if it is undefined?

Comment: No; I'm talking about the parameter that _you pass_ to the callback.  The callback itself is passed to you by `async.forEach()`, and is never undefined.

Comment: I think you're mistaken.  `forEach` only passes an error to the final callback.  You may be thinking of `map`.